# GDI+ drawn grid on PictureBox usercontrol doesn't scale with DPI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm making an "eyedropper" tool that lets you select a colour on the screen. I display the colours in a 7x7 zoomed in pixel grid. It works great except for one thing. If the tool runs on a DPI scaled environment, the grid falls out of place with the crosshair.

This is a screenshot at 150% DPI scaling (4k monitor). The crosshairs are off by a few px:
[image: wrong]

At 100% scaling, the crosshair fits neatly within the grid and the picturebox stays 49x49px.

Here's the code for the custom control (you don't need the eyedropper functionality to see the issue, just plop the control on a form and you'll see what I mean).

**For the record:** I've tried adding DPI awareness to the manifest, that doesn't do anything.

Using C#, Winforms, and .NET 5.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ColourPicker
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Basically just a picture box but with a hacky grid and crosshair (not DPI friendly)
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PixelPictureBox : PictureBox
    {
        private int cellCount;
        private int cellSize;


        public PixelPictureBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        public PixelPictureBox(IContainer container)
        {
            container.Add(this);

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <value>Set this to Nearest Neighbour to avoid quality loss on zoom</value>
        public InterpolationMode InterpolationMode { get; set; }

        /// <value>Show the grid</value>
        public bool ShowGrid { get; set; } = true;

        /// <value>How many wide/high are each grid "pixel"</value>
        public int GridSize { get; set; } = 7;

        /// <value>Returns colour of the pixel in the middle of the crosshair.</value>
        public Color CentreColour
        {
            get
            {
                var bmp = new Bitmap(Image);
                return bmp.GetPixel(bmp.Width / 2, bmp.Height / 2);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs paintEventArgs)
        {
            paintEventArgs.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
            paintEventArgs.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode;
            base.OnPaint(paintEventArgs);

            cellCount = GridSize * GridSize;
            cellSize = Width / GridSize;

            if (ShowGrid && cellCount > 0 && cellSize > 0)
            {
                var g = paintEventArgs.Graphics;
                var gridPen = new Pen(Color.Black);

                // Crosshair
                var crosshairColour = Color.Fuchsia;
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(crosshairColour),
                    new Rectangle(Width / 2 - cellSize / 2, 0, cellSize, Height / 2 - cellSize / 2));
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(crosshairColour),
                    new Rectangle(Width / 2 - cellSize / 2, Height / 2 + cellSize / 2, cellSize,
                        Height / 2 - cellSize / 2));
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(crosshairColour),
                    new Rectangle(0, Height / 2 - cellSize / 2, Width / 2 - cellSize / 2, cellSize));
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(crosshairColour),
                    new Rectangle(Width / 2 + cellSize / 2, Height / 2 - cellSize / 2, Width / 2 - cellSize / 2,
                        cellSize));

                // Grid
                for (var x = 0; x < cellCount; x++)
                    g.DrawLine(gridPen, x * cellSize, 0, x * cellSize, cellCount * cellSize);

                for (var y = 0; y < cellCount; y++)
                    g.DrawLine(gridPen, 0, y * cellSize, cellCount * cellSize, y * cellSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your app needs to be DpiAware. -- Specify the .Net version in use.

Comment: @Jimi tried that (in my post I said I added DPI awareness to the manifest and that I'm using .NET 5)

Comment: [Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.sethighdpimode) (`Program.cs`) -- [HighDpiMode.PerMonitorV2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.highdpimode). Comment out what you have set in `app.manifest` (read the notes in the first link) -- You need to design your app at 100% scale -- See also [What’s new in Windows Forms in .NET 6.0 Preview 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-in-windows-forms-in-net-6-0-preview-5/) -- Yes, I did miss that last statement.

Comment: The problem is that dpiAware is turned on.  At 100%, 49x49 is very convenient, but at 150% the control grows to 73x73.  No nice multiple of 7, cellsize can't tile the control surface anymore.  Doing the math with float and RectangleF is a simple workaround.  Or force the control size to be an exact multiple of the grid size.

Comment: @HansPassant what do you mean do the math with float? Would floats automatically adjust based on DPI? A little confused but would love to explore this